# Stack Trace of cross-thread exceptions with Invoke

Tags: .net, multithreading, exception

When an exception happens after calling Invoke, .NET shows the stack trace as if the error happens while calling Invoke.

Example below: .NET will say the error happen in UpdateStuff instead of UpdateStuff -> BadFunction

Is there a way to catch the "real" exception and show the correct stack trace?

```
Private Sub UpdateStuff()

    If (Me.InvokeRequired) Then
        Me.Invoke(New UpdateStuffDelegate(AddressOf UpdateStuff))
        Return
    End If

    Badfunction()

End Sub

Private Sub BadFunction()

    Dim o As Object

    o.ToString()

End Sub
```

Comment: @Steven I will when I'll find one...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is less than perfect.  The exception is caught and re-thrown in the thread that called Invoke().  Necessarily, it is missing the stack frames of the code in the UI thread, they are already unwound by the time the exception is re-thrown.  That it doesn't use the InnerException property is not great.

One workaround is to catch the exception in the invoked method and store it in a private field.  A better one is to use BeginInvoke instead of Invoke.  That will raise the exception in the UI thread directly.

Answer (score 3):

Check the [InnerException](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.exception.innerexception.aspx) property of the exception.

Comment: The InnerException is set to nothing

Comment: It looks like my answer, while being reasonably good advice in general, does not apply here.

Answer (score 1):

try ... catch block perhaps.

Comment: I tought of that, I might need to store the Exception somewhere and fetch it later.

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the [TargetSite](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.exception.targetsite.aspx) on the exception itself, it will give you the name of the function that was dynamically invoked (or it gets the method that threw the current exception):
Name    "BadFunction"   String

The exception contains the actual exception that you have from the invocation: System.NullReferenceException {"Object reference not set to an instance of an object."}  System.Exception

Here is my stack trace:
   at WindowsApplication1.Form1.BadFunction() in C:\Development\Test\WindowsApplication1\WindowsApplication1\Form1.vb:line 35
   at WindowsApplication1.Form1.UpdateStuff() in C:\Development\Test\WindowsApplication1\WindowsApplication1\Form1.vb:line 22

Comment: Are you sure TargetSite is correct?  As far as I can tell, it only reveals the name of the method being called.

Comment: TargetSite gives MarshaledInvoke, not BadFunction. Maybe InvokeRequired was false when you tried the sample.

Answer (score 0):

Check out https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/386582/control-invoke-exception-handling
which describes this issue in detail, and allows you to vote for it so the Visual Studio team might put it on their priority list again (it's marked "Won't Fix" at the moment).

Answer (score 0):

Hans mentioned two options. Six years later, there's a third that I find convenient. Just wrap your call in a delegate that can preserve the exception in your local scope, then use it:

```cs
Exception exceptionFromDelegate = null;
formForSynchronizing.Invoke(new Action(() =>
{
    try
    {
        SomeMethod();
    }
    catch (Exception error)
    {
        exceptionFromDelegate = error;
    }
}));
if (exceptionFromDelegate != null)
{
    // with .net 4.5 you can do this:
    ExceptionDispatchInfo.Capture(exceptionFromDelegate).Throw();

    // otherwise maybe go straight to your error reporting system
    ReportException(exceptionFromDelegate);
}
```